# adding items belongs_to relationship to Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, belongs-to

I'm using active admin for my rails app. I have a customer model which belongs_to a department and also belongs_to a delivery_time.

In my admin folder I have a customer.rb file for active admin.

That file looks like this -

```
ActiveAdmin.register Customer
  index do |customer|
      column :department, :sortable => false
      column :delivery_time, :sortable => false
  end
end
```

Essentially, I'm trying to customise the customer section of active admin to show the name of department they belong to and what delivery time they belong to.

The department model has a name and a some other properties - the name of the department is showing in my active admin screen  - all works as expected. 
The delivery_time model two properties has a date, which is of type date and availabilty - which is a boolean.

The delivery_time is showing up as -

```
#<DeliveryTime:0x00000107984268>
```

How do I show the date property of the delivery time model?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The columns in the index can be customized this way:

```
  index do |customer|
      column :department, :sortable => false
      column "Delivery time", :sortable => false do |cust|
          cust.delivery_time.strftime("%X")
      end
  end
```

See the [ActiveAdmin doc](http://activeadmin.info/docs/3-index-pages/index-as-table.html) for reference